# Error during installation of dark theme into IBMs RDi

Tags: eclipse, rational-developer-for-i

I thought it was a cool idea to test a dark(er) theme for my RDi IDE.
Therefore I went to google, searched for `RDi dark theme` and got this result: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle.

Now when trying to install the theme via `Help -> Install new Software` the installer shows a message telling me "this template can't be installed. trying different solutions". This takes several minutes to complete (15 "alternative solutions")

After the process has endet (with no solution) I get a message:

> Missing Dependency: For Webclipse Common Core Platform Utilities 13.0.2.201803121006 (com.genuitec.eclipse.core.common.platform 13.0.2.201803121006) is 'package org.apache.commons.httpclient 3.1.0' required, but was not found.

So I tried to search for `package org.apache.commons.httpclient 3.1.0` but there were no results to download for eclipse.

So I owuld be very glad, if someone could tell me where to find a link to download the package or how to install the DevStyle darker theme into RDi

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe RDI is Eclipse version 4.6 which is known as Neon.
Go to help -> Install new Software. In there you want to click "Add..."
Give it any name you would like, but the path you will give it will be: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/

Now, on the bottom of the install new software window, should be a checkbox that says "contact all update sites during install to find required software".
Make sure this is checked.
Now, continue back to the eclipse marketplace and begin installing your new theme and it should work this time since it can now find the dependencies you need.